# Java - using SOAP with generated from WSDL classes

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans, wsdl

I have a `WSDL` schema link. With NetBeans I generated classes from this schema. But I can't understand, how to use it to send request to server? There is a `XXXImplService extends Service` class generated by NetBeans, should I use it? How?

As I think, I need just to create objects (which match `WSDL` methods and classes), set necessary properties and somehow transform this objects into a text of request, then send it with and get text response, which I can transform into classes. Is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

of course you have to use the `WSDL`, follow below steps for a complete client app for a Java web service (JAX-WS):

assuming you have a Web Service like this:

```
@WebService
public class Hello {
    private String message = new String("Hello, ");

    public void Hello() {}

    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return message + name + ".";
    }
}
```

1. Uses the `javax.xml.ws.WebServiceRef` **annotation** to declare a
   reference to a web service. `@WebServiceRef` uses the wsdlLocation
   element to specify the URI of the deployed service’s WSDL file:

   `@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/helloservice/hello?wsdl")
   static HelloService service;`
2. Retrieves a proxy to the service, also known as a port, by invoking
   getHelloPort on the service.

   `Hello port = service.getHelloPort();`
   The port implements the SEI defined by the service.
3. Invokes the port’s sayHello method, passing to the service a name.

   ```
   String response = port.sayHello(name);
   ```

**EDIT:** (request in comments) if the web service request for basic *authentication* and want to pass a username and password you can pass them like this (there are other ways also):

```
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() 
{
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("usr", "pass".toCharArray());
    }
};

Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator );
```

> however if you want authentication in application level not on basic
>   HTTP [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/) can be useful.

Comment: I start to understand, but there're still a few questions.
My generated `XXXImplService` class doesn't have method getPort with specificated return type; there're a few getPort() methods from `Service` class. For example:
`public <T> T getPort(Class<T> serviceEndpointInterface)`. How can I use this method to call any WSDL method? And if some of WSDL methods gives arguments with types from WSDL schema, how can I create this arguments?

Comment: you don't need something like `getPort()` to be generated, [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html) is a link which I think can be useful as you using netbeans. I hope you'll finally fix the issue, good luck and sorry if didn't understand you well.

Comment: Yes, this link is really useful, thanks! Don't know how I didn't notice it :) But there's a new question, I generate Java methods like described in this link, but my web service requires http basic authorization. How can I set login and password?

Comment: @gth99, question edited, for authorization you need to research more but if you meant authentication there is some ways for it, I mentioned one however you need to try and search again!! like all of us. good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement your code in this generated service impl and web method now. So when you will be calling the service end point and a specific method, through a web service client ( SOAP UI etc), these generated classes will take the call and route through service impl, to your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial will help you to do it step by step. Since you have already created stub classes, skip the first part. Focus on "Web service invocation" section.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-apacheaxis/index.html?ca=dat